# Looping VBA query

Tags: vba, excel

Im new to VBA/self teaching, I've made the below code but as you can see it is horrible and long, I have tried with no suceess to made into a loop changing the value in "K1" and the value in "M7"  the below code(its long and manual)  essentially it just changes and set factor in "Lu.k1" and copies the resulting changed value in trainers.s30 to regional.m7 repeats changing LU.k1 to 2 copies and pastes trainers.s30 into regional.m8 etc up to lu.k1=8

Any help would be awsome

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("LU").Select
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"

Sheets("Trainers").Select
Range("S30").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Regional").Select
Range("M7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'next change

Sheets("LU").Select
  Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"

Sheets("Trainers").Select
Range("S30").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Regional").Select
Range("M8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Sheets("LU").Select
      Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"

Sheets("Trainers").Select
Range("S30").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Regional").Select
Range("M9").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            Sheets("LU").Select
              Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"

Sheets("Trainers").Select
Range("S30").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Regional").Select
Range("M10").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

                   Sheets("LU").Select
                     Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"

Sheets("Trainers").Select
Range("S30").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Regional").Select
Range("M11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



                          Sheets("LU").Select
                            Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6"

Sheets("Trainers").Select
Range("S30").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Regional").Select
Range("M12").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem much more clearly to get any meaningful help

Comment: You should watch this series [Excel VBA Introduction - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  This video is the most relavent [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Comment: Thomas this was very helpful, thanks for the assitance

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a loop to reduce redundant code.

```
Sub erqwtrw()
    Dim wsLU As Worksheet, wsTRN As Worksheet, i As Long, mx As Long

    Set wsLU = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("lu")
    Set wsTRN = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("trainers")

    mx = 8
    wsLU.Range("E1") = 4

    With Worksheets("regional")
        .Range("M7").Resize(mx, 1).NumberFormat = wsTRN.Range("S30").NumberFormat
        For i = 1 To mx
            wsLU.Range("I1").Resize(1, 3) = Array(2, 3, i)
            .Range("M6").Offset(i, 0) = wsTRN.Range("S30").Value
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works a treat i will shamelessly use it in the future.